# How to create javascript object from concatenated key value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to create an object from a variable created with concateneated key value pairs.
HardCoded (it is an array as dataSource for a jquery datatable), it looks like this:

```
obj = {
          totalValue: valVar,
          totalReceiptValue: receiptVar
      }
dataSourceArray.push(obj);
```

My variable is:

```
cumulator ="totalValue:8573.0000,totalReceiptValue:3573.00,"
```

I've tried this,

```
var obj = {};
const name = ""; 
const value = cumulator;
obj[name] = value;
dataSourceArray.push(obj);
```

but then I have an extra key  i.e.  "": in the object which of course fails for my requirements.
How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `split, map reduce` functions.

Try this.

```js
const input = "totalValue:8573.0000,totalReceiptValue:3573.00,";
const result = input.split(',').filter(Boolean).map(function(text) {
 return text.split(':')
}).reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  acc[curr[0]] = curr[1]
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thx again, but  'const [key, val]' gives a syntax error in IE with 'Expected identifier'

Comment: Got it!!  ( output[split[0].trim()] = split[1].trim(); )Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there are no extra `:` or `,` signs that could mess with the logic, it can be achieved simply by spliting the strings and using the built in method `Object.prototype.fromEntries`

```js
const input = "totalValue:8573.0000,totalReceiptValue:3573.00,";

const output = Object.fromEntries( // combine entries into object
  input.split(",") // divide into pairs
  .filter(Boolean) // remove empty elements (comma at the end)
  .map((el) => el.split(":")) // divide the pair into key and value
)

console.log(output)
```

There apparently being some problems with IE and Edge, the code above can be fixed by writing own implementation of from Entries and opting to not use arrow functions.

```js
const input = "totalValue:8573.0000,totalReceiptValue:3573.00,";

const entries = input.split(",") // divide into pairs

const output = {};
for (let i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
  if (!entries[i]) continue; // remove empty elements (comma at the end)
  const [key, val] = entries[i].split(":"); // divide the pair into key and value
  output[key]=val; // combine entries into object
}

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Hi and thanks, but the fat arrow and .fromEntries are not supported by IE and apparently .fromEntries is also an issue with Edge.